# set sequence and limits

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the next question.
$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $A_{n} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be given by $A_{n}=\{ x\in\mathbb{R} | -\frac{1}{n}<x<n\}$.

Find $\limsup A_{n}$ and $\liminf A_{n}$ by finding $\bigcap A_{n}$ and $\bigcup A_{n}$.

I think that we need to prove that $\bigcap A_{n} = (-1,\infty)$ and $\bigcup A_{n} = [0,1)$ but I'm not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You are $\color{red}{\text{not}}$ right. $\color{red}\bigcap A_{n} = (-1,\infty)$ and $\color{ red} \bigcup A_{n} = [0,1)$ are not true.

The true statements are

$$\color{green}\bigcup A_{n} = (-1,\infty)\tag a$$
and
$$\color{green} \bigcap A_{n} = [0,1)\tag b$$
This how to prove that.

For $(a)$.

For any point of $(-1,\infty)$ there exists an $n$ so that the point in question belongs to $\left(-\frac1n, n \right)$.

For $(b)$.

$[0,1)$ is the set all of whose points belong to all the sets of the form $\left(-\frac1n, n \right)$.

Comment: @Malcolm: Right. Thx. I'm gonna fix immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You've got your guesses mixed up.

In any case, let's turn back to the definitions.
For any indexing $I$ we have that

$$\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i=\{x\,|\,\forall i \in I,\,x\in X_i\}$$

while

$$\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i=\{x\,|\,\exists i \in I,\,x\in X_i\}.$$

Therefore:

- In order to show that $x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i$, you must show that $x$ lies in **all** of the $X_i$.
- In order to show that $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$, you must show that $x$ lies in **at least one** of the $X_i$.

Comment: And what will be $lim inf A_n$ and $lim sup A_n$?

Comment: See [the definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit#The_two_definitions), and be sure to check out the section on monotone sequences.

Comment: So is it $lim inf A_{n} = [0,1]$ and $lim sup A_{n} = (-1,\infty)$?